# telegraf snmp_trap plugin causes an error on AWS Timestream

Tags: telegraf, amazon-timestream, telegraf-inputs-plugin

I'm currently experiencing a small problem with the telegraf snmp_trap plugin on an AWS Timestream database.

On an InfluxDB database, I have no problem. However, on AWs Timestream , the error is as follows: "Failed to write to Timestream database "XXXXX" table "snmp_trap": operation error Timestream Write: WriteRecords, https response error StatusCode: 400, , ValidationException: . Skipping metric!"

```
[agent]
  interval = "30s"
  round_interval = true
  metric_batch_size = 1000
  metric_buffer_limit = 10000
  collection_jitter = "0s"
  flush_interval = "10s"
  flush_jitter = "0s"
  precision = ""
  debug = true
  quiet = false
  logfile = ""
  hostname = ""
  omit_hostname = false
  snmp_translator = "gosmi"

[[inputs.snmp_trap]]

service_address = "udp://:162"

timeout = "5s"

path=["C:/Program Files/InfluxData/telegraf/telegraf-1.29.1/mib"]



[[outputs.timestream]]

  region = "us-east-1"

  database_name = "XXXXX"

  access_key = ""

  secret_key = ""

  create_table_if_not_exists = true

  mapping_mode = "multi-table"

  create_table_magnetic_store_retention_period_in_days = 7

  create_table_memory_store_retention_period_in_hours = 24
```

What I've already tried:

- fine tuning AWS Timestream
- Try searching the telegraf options

Thank you in advance for your help
Best regards